# Force Google App Engine with PHP to Redirect www and remove appspot

Tags: php, google-app-engine, redirect, dns

This is a three part question. I've read through tons of articles on stack overflow, and found partial ways to do it with the Python, but not PHP. I have a Google App Enigne with PHP app and cant seem to figure out how to do the following. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

1. Redirect my-app.appspot.com -> my-custom-domain.com
2. Redirect www.my-custom-domain.com -> my-custom-domain.com
3. How do I create a custom subdomain for my module. Ex. module.my-app.appspot. -> module.my-custom-domain.com

I tried creating a module title "www" with the sole purpose of redirecting it to the domain with the www, but that doesn't appear to work. Once I created a CNAME for www in the Developer Console and updated the DNS, it just shows the main site and no redirection occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This is up to your php script since you can't change the appspot domain. Check the hostname and send a redirect to your custom domain if it ends in appspot.com.
2. Add the 'www.' domain as custom domain to your app by navigating to your Google Developers Console.
   Go to you project. Open Compute -> App Engine -> Settings -> Custom domains.
   Then handle the domain the same way as in **1.**
3. Sorry, i have no answer to this on at the moment. I guess that it should work once you added your base domain as custom domain.